# Trouble installing Sublime command line tools

Tags: command-line, installation, sublimetext2

I followed the advice of [this blog post](http://steverydz.com/2012/04/27/sublime-text-2-opening-files-and-folders-from-the-command-line/) and it didn't work. Below is my output. What can I do to fix this?

```
~/code/rails/adam $ echo "export PATH=~/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
~/code/rails/adam $ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
ln: /Users/adamzerner/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

**New output:**

```
~/code/rails/adam $ mkdir ~/bin
~/code/rails/adam $ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
~/code/rails/adam $ subl
-bash: subl: command not found
~/code/rails/adam $ subl --help
-bash: subl: command not found
~/code/rails/adam $
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `~/bin` directory before you can create a symlink in it. Run

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

then

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: Does it matter which folder I'm in when I run these commands?

Comment: No, `~` represents your home folder, so the path are absolute.

Comment: @AdamZerner try restarting Terminal.